# Url without "slash, dot" words in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `stringex` gem to make url for items, but there is a problem with adding `"-dot"` and `"-slash"` words to url if name includes characters like `"."`, `"/"` and other symbols.

How to turn of this conversion of giving "name" to symbols in the url?

If item name: Bike 2.2/2.0

url by default: `bike-2-dot-2-slash-2-dot-0`
I need just: 
`bike-2-2-2-0`

Comment: set `:allow_slash` option for `acts_as_url` to `true` & it will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with gsub:

```
"bike-2-dot-2-slash-2-dot-0".gsub(/-(dot|slash)/, '')
```